# transform value of Dictionary using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 2 collections in play here:

- a `Dictionary<int, Privilege>` that acts a cache
- a `Dictionary<Workflow, List<enumPrivilege>>` that represents the permissions a given user has on every existem workflow.

the thing here is that the cache has the full version of the privilege (along with the id, a friendly description, a text explanation, etc...) and I need to convert the `Dictionary<Workflow, List<enumPrivilege>>` to `Dictionary<Workflow, List<Privilege>>`...

Can I do that using a single lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends if you have logic that transforms a single enumeration value to the respective object, e.g. a factory.

In order to transform one `Dictionary<K, List<V>>` you can use the `ToDictionary()` method which accepts the `KeyValuePair` two times, so you can use it first time for the key and second time for the value

Let's say we have

```
 Dictionary<string, List<string>> a = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

And want to transform it to Dictionary `b` which is `string, List<int>`

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> b 
    = a.ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key, 
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(int.Parse).ToList()
    );
```

The same way you should be able to turn the enumeration to object, by mapping (`Select`) each enum value and execute the factory upon it

```
Dictionary<Workflow, List<Privilege>> b 
    = a.ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key, 
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(PrivilegeFactory.Create).ToList()
    );
```

Or if the dictionary's key `int` is the `enumPrivile` value you can do

```
Dictionary<Workflow, List<Privilege>> b 
    = a.ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key, 
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(t => cacheDictionary[(int)t])
    );
```